# New SimpleCursorAdapter whenever data changes?

Tags: java, android, simplecursoradapter

I'm just starting out with Android development and have been building a simple app that uses a `ListActivity`, a `SQLiteDatabase`, and a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

On the Android developer website there is an example project that demonstrates the usage of the `SimpleCursorAdadpter`. Looking at the implementation, whenever the underlying database is modified as a result of some user action, the `ListActivity` explicitly calls the following function to "refresh" the list:

```java
private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
    mNotesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(mNotesCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, mNotesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

It looks like a new `SimpleCursorAdapter` is created every time and bound to the view with `setListAdapter()`. Is this the best/cleanest implementation? The fact that this is on the Android website lends it a lot of credibility, however I looked at the `CursorAdapter` documentation and saw there is a `changeCursor()` method that seems to lend itself to a cleaner implementation than the one above, but I'm just not sure what that might look like.

Maybe I'm just fretting over nothing, but coming from the C/C++ world, and seeing this "new" object created each time you insert/delete a row from the database seems a bit heavy-handed.

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter should always be created only once...there is no point of creating adapter whenever there is change in underlying database....instead of creating completely new adapter....changeCursor() or requery() is best option. I also wonder why they have done in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You can see that a lot of times. For small lists that may not produce any problems when list is always created in onResume. But that's no good style. You can use cursor.changeCursor() or adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I've decided to refactor the code so that the `SimpleCursorAdapter` instance is now a member of the `ListActivity` class and gets instantiated (with a null cursor) in the `onCreate()` method. Then, whenever the dataset changes (or the first time the list needs to get filled), I all my utility function to re-query the database and return a new `Cursor` instance. I then call the `startManagingCursor()` method on the activity and the `changeCursor()` method on the adapter, passing in the newly-created cursor object.